# Test companies for development of apps on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to look into best practices for Facebook app development.  While I've read I can create test accounts by visiting http://www.facebook.com/developers/become_test_account.php, is there also a way to also create development companies?  I'll likely be doing some app development work for my employer, but would prefer a non-live test company to test apps with.  Are there any other facets or recommendations to be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Facebook app development is a pretty confusing one-sided process.  You can either own a personal user account or business user account, but not both.  And both types of accounts are not the same thing.  Real user accounts can create real valid "pages" though which is what users would become fans of.  Test user accounts (via the link provided in my initial post) cannot create pages, however.